# Cheerio error, undefined not a function // Is this the correct way?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

When trying to run code, i keep getting the error `$.find('.market_listing_item_name_block').each()` - undefined is not a function, pointing at find. I thought that find was a function in cheerio? To be fair, i'm not sure if i'm even doing this right, here is my code :

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio')
$ = cheerio.load('#searchResultsRows')
var url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730'
xhr.get(url).success(function(r){
    $.find(".market_listing_item_name_block").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).find(".market_listing_item_name").text();
        console.log(name)
    })
})
```

xhr is an object that essentially acts like AJAX.

the way i was doing it before in chrome, was:

```
var url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730'
var itemDiv = $("<div></div>")
$.get(url).success(function(r){
    d = $(r).find('#searchResultsRows')
    itemDiv.append(d)
})
```

and then:

```
itemDiv.find(".market_listing_item_name_block").each(function(){
   var name = $(this).find(".market_listing_item_name").text();
   console.log(name) // would normally do other things, but for the purpose of this post, i'm just console logging the name
})
```

how exactly would I be able to re-create that ^ in node/cheerio? I believe i'm missing a few steps obviously. any help is extremely appreciated, thanks.

Comment: probably find does not return an object that would have a method of `each`, so your query comes back empty. Are you sure that this is a correct invocation: `$.find(".market_listing_item_name_block")`? Should it not be something like the code below that:  `$(r).find(".market_listing_item_name_block")`?

Comment: Do a `console.log($.find(".market_listing_item_name_block"));` and see if it has the method .each, also, paste the result here

Comment: @Datsik doing it with $.find still returns undefined is not a function, now as guessimtoolate said, I tried $(r).find and it returned an object. https://i.gyazo.com/4eeb0a86cc7f3c351347c52c9503a9ab.png

Answer (score 11):

When you get an element, you need to use wrap that element with `$` before doing further selections

```
const $ = Cheerio.load(body)
const list = $('div.titles li')

list.each((index, li) => {
  const title = $(li).find('p.title').text()

  console.log(title)
})
```